# Why use @ObservableObject when you might as well use @StateObject?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've been learning about swiftUI and `@StateObject` and `@ObservedObject` and thought I grasped it until I realized I could exchange `@ObservedObject` with `@StateObject` without any difference to the code behaviour. Consider this example:

```
class SharedModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var value: String = "Initial Value"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var sharedModel = SharedModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Value in ContentView: \(sharedModel.value)")
            TextField("ContentView textfield", text: $sharedModel.value)

            SubView(sharedModel: sharedModel)
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    @ObservedObject var sharedModel: SharedModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Value in SubView: \(sharedModel.value)")
            
            TextField("sub textfield", text: $sharedModel.value)
        }
    }
}
```

Writing something in either `TextField` will update the text in both `Text` views. So, ContentView and SubView will update when the property of SharedModel is updated. Great. But then I played around a bit and changed `@ObservedObject` to `@StateObject` and didn't notice any difference. It worked as before. The way I though it would work is that if a property is annotated with `@StateObject` then it's the source of truth and won't relay changes to other `@StateObject` properties.

So what's the deal here? What's the point of `@ObservedObject` and why should I use it if `@StateObject` works equally fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StateObject`’s main difference is that it has storage within SwiftUI it can preserve an object when the `View` is reloaded.

You might not notice any differences but using `ObservedObject` to initialize will cause leaks, inconsistent behavior and unnecessary loss of data.

> SwiftUI might create or recreate a view at any time, so it’s important that initializing a view with a given set of inputs always results in the same view. As a result, it’s unsafe to create an observed object inside a view. Instead, SwiftUI provides the StateObject property wrapper, which creates a single source of truth for a reference type that you store in a view hierarchy.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app

When going from `StateObject` to `StateObject` you don’t get a new object because it is a `class` is a reference type and they would both be pointing to the same address. You would need a “deep” copy for them to be completely different.

You would have 2 different o nexts trying to own the same thing within SwiftUI so you might end up with leaks.

The new `Observable` can do what you describe if you pass an `Observable` to a `State` SwiftUI now creates a deep copy for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about **three** different things:

- `@ObservedObject` is a property wrapper and is used – similar to value type `@Binding` - for reference type objects which are not owned by the current view. In the first version of SwiftUI it was also the property wrapper for objects owned by the current view.
- `@StateObject` is a property wrapper and is used - similar to value type `@State` – exclusively for reference type objects which are owned by the current view. It has replaced `@ObservedObject` in later versions of SwiftUI for the  *owned* types. For compatibility reasons `@ObservedObject` still works but it's not recommended.
- `ObservableObject` on the other hand is a protocol and is required for classes created with the `@StateObject` wrapper. It refreshes the affected view whenever one of its `@Published` properties changes.

Please note the distinct difference between `ObservableObject` and `@ObservedObject`.

Comment: I see now that I made a misstake and wrote observableObject instead of ObservedObject at one place. However, the question isn't related to observableObject, only ObservedObject and why nothing happens when it's replaced by StateObject.

Comment: I answered the question in the `@StateObject` section.

Answer (score 0):

In the first version of SwiftUI we only had `@ObservedObject` where the object was owned by something else, e.g. by a singleton, that stored all of the model structs in an `@Published` array and was responsible for loading and saving. Then in the second version `@StateObject` was added which provided the capability for the object to be owned by the `View` and init when the screen appeared and de-init when it disappeared, i.e. using it for async view data loaded via a Combine pipeline. Since now we can use the async/await  capable `.task` for managing the lifecycle of async work related to view data we don't need `@StateObject` anymore.

For non-async view data we use `@State` (can group related vars in a struct), `let` and `@Binding var` and avoid the use heavy-weight objects like the one in your example code that will slow down SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

@ObservableObject:

```
@ObservableObject is used to declare and inject an observable object into a view. An observable object is a class that conforms to the ObservableObject protocol. It allows you to create an object whose properties can be observed for changes, and when these properties change, the associated view is updated. You use @ObservableObject when you want to inject an external observable object into a view, typically when you're sharing the same instance of the observable object among multiple views.

class UserData: ObservableObject {
@Published var username: String = "User"
```

}

struct ContentView: View {
@ObservedObject var userData: UserData = UserData()

```
var body: some View {
    // Use userData properties in the view
}
```

}

@StateObject:

```
@StateObject is used for managing the lifecycle of an observable object within a view. It's specifically designed for creating and managing the lifecycle of an observable object within a view. When you use @StateObject, SwiftUI manages the lifecycle of the associated object, ensuring it persists for the duration of the view's existence. It's primarily used when the view itself is responsible for creating and owning the observable object, and the object should be recreated only when the view is re-initialized (e.g., due to the view being reconstructed after a state change).
class UserData: ObservableObject {
@Published var username: String = "User"
```

}

struct ContentView: View {
@StateObject var userData: UserData = UserData()

```
var body: some View {
    // Use userData properties in the view
}}
```

In summary, @ObservableObject is used to inject an external observable object into a view, while @StateObject is used to manage the lifecycle of an observable object created within a view. It's essential to choose the appropriate property wrapper based on whether the object is created and owned by the view itself or if it's shared among multiple views.

Comment: Thanks for the response; but why can you then just change observedObject to stateObject with the same result? What's the difference or downside?